# Printing a particular portion of a page

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to print a specific div inside a page

```
var printCalender = function ()
{
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = "<div style='text-align:center'><h2>Academic Calender - " + $scope.selectedSessionSelection + "</h2></div><br /><br />" + document.all.item('printportion').innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that, if I cancel printing, then I cannot execute any javascript on the page.

Comment: If you have the javascript console of the browser open during this, do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: why u use return false..! remove it

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. But you might want to check the external forces in this function. For example $scope.selectedSessionSelection and/or document.all.item('printportion')

Comment: Use media queries it will easy this work

Comment: I commented out return false but still found the same problem. And I do not know how media queries will help since my problem is in the javascript of the page after cancelling print

Answer (score 2):

Use a Print only CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

This will only be read in print mode.

Then you can manipulate styles for print only.

Comment: I am not using any css for print or even for the web display.

Comment: @Shuaib I'm suggesting that you can as a solution to your problem.